# Docker for mac --privileged not working

Tags: docker, container

I have a docker container run via the below command:
docker run --privileged=true -it --name mysql -p 3306:3306 centos:7 bash

When I tried to start the mysql daemon in the container, it still returned the below error:
[root@cd6f5c9f4449 /]# systemctl start mysql
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Please suggest if there is any way to resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not run systemctl or systemd inside of the container. Instead, you should run the application directly in the foreground. An image to run mysql is available on the docker hub, and you can also review the Dockerfile's used to generate those images:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/